# Draw a circle with different colored section

Tags: html, canvas, 2d, dart

So I want to draw a circle, filled blue with a black and red outline. The red part is determined by the `look` angle. The `ctx` variable holds the 2d context.
Relevant code:

```
ctx..lineWidth = 0.5
   ..fillStyle = "#0000AA"
   ..strokeStyle = "red";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, look - PI / 6, look + PI / 6);
ctx..fill()
   ..closePath()
   ..stroke()
   ..beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, look + PI / 6, look - PI / 6);

ctx..fill()
   ..closePath()
   ..stroke();
```

This, however draws an additional red line inside the circle, that I don't want. How can I get rid of this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the closePath when drawing the red line.

closePath will draw a line connecting the endpoints of your red arc (not what you want).

Comment: Thanks! That worked, had to remove the other (black) line too and then adjust the angles, because there was a little white gap.